# How to remove a task from Running Tasks list in Android

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a Listview Layout with all Running Applications, Label, Package Name, I need to remove a particular application from Running Applications list and need refresh the ListView items.

I have try to use following code,

```
final String item = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(pos);
                    ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);                 
                    activityManager.killBackgroundProcesses(item);    
                    ((BaseAdapter) lstview.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
```

but its not removing the items from ListView. Please let me know what wrong I did., the "item" variable have selected items, package name. And also added the following permissions as well,

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES"/> 
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RESTART_PACKAGES"/>
```

but its not working. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

i got it! your code is correct but you must have this permission to show tasks

> android.permission.GET_TASKS

Comment: yes, I have a StringArray adapter, that adapter loading on ListView, but, I need to kill a running app which is shows in listview and need to refresh StringArray Adapter.

Comment: @AbleAlias Ok, but when you kill an app you must remove it from array or revalidate the array then notify all

Comment: I believe, the "activityManager.killBackgroundProcesses(item); " function is not working as expected, its not killing the app.

Comment: Ok ,i will create a full app for you

Comment: Thank You dear friend, that would be great help.